# How to declare JSF resource bundle when it resides in JBoss 7 module?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-modules

I am moving our JSF messages.properties outside the war so QA and ops people can modify messages without generating a new war.

I've created a JBoss 7 module and placed the messages.properties file in $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/acme/revenue/main/messages.properties. 
I updated jboss-deployment-structure.xml to include

```
<module name="com.acme.revenue"/>
```

And I put a module.xml file in $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/acme/revenue/main.  It contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.acme.revenue">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

This all works. In the java code I can call:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", Locale.getDefault());
bundle.getString("TargetingKey")
```

and it returns the translated value "Income Targeting". However in the JSF .xhtml files code calls #{messages.TargetingKey} and it is not working because JSF doesn't seem to find the resource bundle.

Before the change the faces-config.xml contained the following and it worked fine:

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>com.acme.revenue.messages</base-name>
    <var>messages</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

How can I fix this JSF declaration to find the bundle, and display the messages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the module you gave the `name=com.acme.revenue` this acts like a **static import** for the `faces-config.xml` so in the **resource-bundle** declaration you must put in the **base-name** only the **file name** of your properties file.

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>messages</base-name>
    <var>messages</var>
</resource-bundle>
```